# Removing simple_form_for default error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using simple_form_for. I need to disable the default error message in the form

My form looks like this:

```
f.input :value, label: 'Amount', error: false
```

In my model I have:

```
validates :value, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01,
           message: "Amount must be greater than or equal to 0.01 " }
```

On the UI I can see the message:
'Value Amount must be greater than or equal to 0.01 '

I dont know what I am missing here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not a simple_form_for issue. ActiveRecord returns name of attribute with the error message. So just had to remove that.

In my en.yml I wrote:

```
activerecord:
    attributes:
      gift_card:
        value: "Amount"
```

In my model I changed my code to:

```
validates :value, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
```

This returns the message on the UI:
'Amount must be greater than or equal to 0.01 '

Check this [link from rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation)

Hope this helps someone